# PHP Windows - Return drive letter from path

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the drive letter from a path in PHP windows.

I'm in this directory:

```
c:\Program Files\Adobe\
```

and I want to return:

```
c
```

What's the best way to do this? Is there an alternative to parse_url(), but for local paths (and usable under Windows?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `substr` function from php.

```
$dir = 'c:/...';
$letter = substr($dir,0,1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `explode` in php, which actually works similar to `split`.

```
 $drive = explode(":",$path)[0];
```